# NSDictionary to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a JSON request getting this:

```
bills =     (
        {
    id = 1;
    name = "Cursus Nibh Venenatis";
    value = "875.24";
},
        {
    id = 2;
    name = "Elit Fusce";
    value = "254.02";
}
);
```

I'm creating a NSDictionary for it.

I'm using JSONKit and I wanna know how can I populate my UITableView with this values? Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

```
NSLog(@"my dictionary = %@", resultsDictionary);
my dictionary = {
bills =     (
            {
        id = 1;
        name = "Cursus Nibh Venenatis";
        value = "875.24";
    },
            {
        id = 2;
        name = "Elit Fusce";
        value = "254.02";
    }
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like In the result dictionary, you are having an Array. Where each object in your Array is a dictionary. Tryout the following code.

```
NSArray *billsArray = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"bills"];
```

give `[[billsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]` in your tableView datasource method `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Bills is an Array not a dictionary.

Comment: Inside the bills object the values are not in key-value pair. then how can it be a dictionary. Could you pls check the above code.

Comment: WOW, thats right dude! Thanks a lot! One line solved my problem! So, JSONKit parses json into array on this: resultsDictionary = [jsonData objectFromJSONData];
    [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"bills"]; ?

Comment: So, NSArray *billsArray = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"bills"]; is making by app give SIGABRT signal. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `bills` dictionary is composed of an array of smaller dictionaries. You'd access it like this;

```
get the top Dictionary bills.
access each dictionary inside (for loop, etc) and create an array
load table view data from previously created array
```

Edit*

```
NSDictionary *billsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[resultsDictionary objectForKey:bills]];
NSMutableArray *dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //make this an ivar and your tabelView's data source.
for(NSDictionary *dict in billsDictionary){
  [dataSource addObject:dict];
}
[tableView reloadData];


//then in your tableView cell
cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]]

//Repeat for whatever else you want to add to the cell (subtitle, image, etc.) Hope this helps.
```

Comment: It says that 'NSDictionary' may not respond to 'objectAtIndex'.

Comment: How can I access each Dictionary? I dont know how to proceed with it.

Comment: Could you please post your bills dictionary NSLog?

Comment: Updated, hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Nice! That billsDictionary I dont have to declare?

Comment: All of this inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes you do have to declare it. Only the cell text part goes inside. The rest you do somewhere else, hence the reloadData.

Comment: I think it goes all inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath because it needs dataSource, right? I still dont get it. Sorry.

Comment: When you finish parsing your JSON do the first part of my answer, and declare `dataSource` as a global variable.

Comment: How do I declare a global variable? In .h file? Sorry, im a beginner.

Comment: :) Yes in your .h file or private interface().

Comment: Tried it out. Got this: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithDictionary:copyItems:]: dictionary argument is not an NSDictionary'