# Presenting NSDictionary in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSDictionary to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745233/nsdictionary-to-uitableview)

I have NSDictionary with keys, for example, @"first_name". I want to show objects for this keys using UITableView. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: This tagged with iOS. Do you mean UITableView or this mis-tagged?

Comment: Do you mean UITableView?  iOS has no NSTableView.

Comment: Sorry... I mean UITableView...

Comment: Then the answer is UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745233/nsdictionary-to-uitableview, sorry... Thanks for trying to help

Comment: @HotLicks Rather `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: @H2CO3 -- Yep.  It's a delegate too, of course, just a differently-named one.

Comment: @HotLicks Let's agree on that it's a *protocol* :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the ui table view delegate and then order somehow the dictionary (choose the order that you wish, or create an array from the dictionary sorting the keys).Implementing the protocol is the solution.